# Change width of variation selector dropdown?

Tags: wordpress, width, dropdown

Is there a way of reducing the width of the variation selector dropdown in Wordpress with CSS?

The standard width far exceeds what is required.
Here is an image of the dropdown.
[Dropdown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8G1eO.jpg)

Any assistance would be appreciated

The web site is trapbarn.com if one wants to view it on different devices

Comment: Without a way to see the issue in action (either via a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) or via a live URL) I'm afraid we won't be of much help here.

Comment: OK, here is the URL. The dropdown is the one  for  saying "Choose quantity here".